# How to change cursor on the NextGen Gallery Slideshow in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, cursor, nextgen-gallery

I've been trying to work this out all morning. I understand how to to change it -

```
$('selector').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
```

my problem is where to apply it in all the js / css files for the NextGen Plugin. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using !important on your css file instead of using the jQuery to change this.

```
.selector {cursor:pointer !important;}
```

using the !important means that it will ignore any other propriety cursor that has been declared. I don't known that nextgen plugin but you can check the classes of the element on Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and even IE.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: doesn't work. because it's a slideshow there isn't actually an image on the page - it's all in built, so the cursor stays default. thanks though!

Comment: even generated html builty by javascript should follow the rules of the css file, see how to look at the classes of the element on the element viewer of your browser

Comment: just had to search through the plugin for the acquired css. thanks!